# Append extension to a string passed by reference

Tags: c++, file, visual-studio-2012

In my code, I would like to do the following i.e. pass the name of string which becomes the fileName that I write to, when the string name is passed by reference, I am unable to use the + operator overloading to append *.txt to my fileName, same code shown below:

```
void myFunction (string &fileName){

   (1)
   fileName += ".txt";
   fstream file; 
   file.open(fileName, iostream::out);
}
```

VS2012 Intellisense shows an error at += saying "no operator matches these operands"
I tried by passing it by adding, which mean += operator can't be used on string names passed by reference. At least thats what I understand.

But when I copy the fileName reference to another string and use that, it produces a file without a name i.e. just a .txt file.

```
string myName = fileName; 
fileName += ".txt"; at (1)
```

The file was produced without any name. Any idea where I could have gone wrong?

Comment: Please give the *exact* error you get. As for "the file was produced without any name", that does not make sense. All files have a name. There is no way to create a file without a name. You *may* have meant that the name was just `".txt"`, but in that case, the code you posted does not match what you actually tried.

Comment: Same error with fileName += std::string(".txt"); ?

Comment: Looks like an Intellisense problem, not your code problem. Dies it compile?

Comment: It doesn't compile when I use the fileName after it is appended with .txt

Comment: Don't describe your code and error messages in free prose, quote them verbatim. Demonstrate **exactly** what the problem is. No demonstration, [no problem](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/140e01ef97bc4744), no question.